# What end of stream dup2 change?

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, dup2

What end of the stream does dub2 ( ) change is it the end the OS is connected to or the end connected to application .

```
int main(){
    FILE* file = fopen("test.txt", "w");    // Create file dexcriptor
    int num = fileno(file);       // Convert FILE* to file descriptor
    dup2(num, STDOUT_FILENO);      // Make STDOUT_FILENO an alias to num
    cout << "happy year";
    close(num);
}
```

this code redirect output to file and not the screen which means that input side of stream is connected now to the file right .

Comment: Your question is barely comprehensible, but `dup2()` doesn't change any end of stream, and it fails if the target file descriptor is already open, as it is in this case because you didn't close `stdin`. Error checking would have revealed that. What 'OS end' has to do with it, or end of stream, is a mystery.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I edited the question so it can be better. I know it's confusing somehow if dup2 doesn't change anything So how cout can now print to the file ,The stream is now connected to a file resource right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `dup2()`, the file descriptor table for the process looks something like this:

```
0 => terminal (stdin)
1 => terminal (stdout)
2 => terminal (stderr)
...
num => file "test.txt"
```

After the `dup2()`, it looks like this:

```
0 => terminal (stdin)
1 => file "test.txt"
2 => terminal (stderr)
...
num => file "test.txt"
```

There's actually an extra level of indirection. There's a file table in the kernel for all open streams, and there's just one entry for the shared opening of `test.txt`. Both descriptors point to that file table entry -- this is what allows them to share the file position.

In the C++ I/O subsystem, `cout` is connected to `STDOUT_FILENO`, so redirecting the descriptor changes where writing to `cout` writes.

Comment: So this just change The kernal end part of file descriptor and cout still outputs or directing or whaever the term to a file descriptor of 1 right,  I mean dup2 just change the Kernal end of the pipe. Which actually makes perfect since but just to be sure

Comment: Basically right, except this isn't a pipe, it's a file.